# Change value inside array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like below in my session

```
Array ( 
    [product-2] => Array ( 
        [product_name] => Hello 
        [pid] => 2 
        [product_price] => 300 
        [quantity] => 1 
        [product_image] => 1630037523.png 
    ) 
)
```

I am looking for change value for field called quantity.

I am searching like below

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="change"){
    
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {
        
        if('product-'.$_POST["pid"] == $key){
            echo "found";
            $new_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            //now do not know how to update it in array
            break;

        }
    
    }   
    
}
```

I am new in PHP and does not know how to update in my array. Let me know if anyone here can help me for same. Thanks!

Comment: Update it with: `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]['quantity'] = $new_quantity;`. Btw, is there a reason why you're prefixing the key with `product-` instead of just using the id straight off? Just seems like extra fluff for no gain.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks a lot, its working fine. since my id is like 1,2,3,4 etc, it was causing some issue so I have added product- prefix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "causing some issue"? In what way? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to iterate through the array. You can just check if the product exist and update the quantity directly:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="change") {
    $key = 'product-' . $_POST['pid'];

    // Check if the product exists in the array and update the quantity if it does
    if (isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key])) {
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
    }        
}
```